# Safe working with FORK from GitHub

Tags: github

I haven't done this before so wanted to make sure I am not messing up anything:

So we have a Central Repo and I wanted to make some changes to one part of the project to experiment some new stuff. RABL for Raisl to be exact.

So if I go to Master and just say Make a Fork, and Then in the web browser browser go to my newly created Fork and say Clone in Mac, then whatever I change and push orgin, will only go to my own Fork, Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. Your fork is independent.

Git is distributed source control system which means that each fork is essentially a different repository.

Also you don't even need to push it to origin if you don't want to share it with anyone. You can commit to your local repo and keep it there (in a separate branch, or even separate repo).

Comment: It depends what do you use in your git server as a front end. Fork is just another repository, here's how you can delete a repository in GitHub: https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repository